# Como obter o ID de um elemento dentro de um div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, div

Tenho uma `div` e umas imagens, cada imagem representa um item em um *array* global. Quando eu arrasto esta imagem para a `div` de edição é habilitado um formulário de edição, caso contrário é habilitado um formulário para criar nova regra e gerar um nova imagem.

Eu preciso saber quando há uma imagem na `div` para habilitar o modo inclusão ou edição e para isto preciso saber o ID dela pois é o índice do *array*.

```
if(document.getElementById("manage").innerHTML == ""){
    console.log("vazio");
else{
    var id = document.getElementById("manage").innerHTML;
    console.log(id.attr("id"));
}
```

Como "id" é uma *string* com o conteúdo:

```
img id="ico-3" class="img-drag" src="images/isp.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"
```

Neste exemplo de IMG, o índice no array é 3.

Comment: Saber o ID é o menor dos seus problemas, até porque o programa já consegue recuperar o ID pelo código que você deixou aqui. O `console.log(id.attr('id'))` recupera o ID da imagem e o mostra no console, assim é só pegar o valor do ID e formatar do jeito que quiser, como um charAt().

Comment: então eu esperava algo como isto que coloquei no log(attr), mais genérico e sem ficar percorrendo a String mas… Vlw pela ajuda.

Comment: Pode postar a estrutura do seu HTML? Esse código que você escreveu não deveria funcionar, pois o `innerHTML` deveria retornar uma string, e como você chamaria o `attr` em uma string?!

Comment: pois é, sua resposta funcionou mas tinha q ficar controlando a quantidade de caractere do id. mas a resposta abaixo caiu como uma luva. vlw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando que você só tenha uma imagem dentro dessa div:

```
// Usando JavaScript puro
var img = document.querySelector("div.manage img.img-drag");
var id = null;
// Se a imagem existe na div
if(img) id = img.id;

// Usando jQuery
var id = $("div.manage img.img-drag").attr("id");
```

Caso a imagem exista `id` será a string do id, caso contrário será `null` (primeiro exemplo) ou `undefined`(jQuery).